# How do I renumber a set of numbers with repetitions in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am going to be working on a project with approximately 10000 lines of data, each identified by unique six digit ID number. Within the data there will be multiple repetitions of the same ID. I must renumber all of the values while maintaining the uniqueness of the individual ID numbers.

For example, 121345 must be renamed to 1 for each repetition of 121345 throughout the data. I have little experience with Excel, so I am unsure how to proceed.

I figured I'd try with a simplified version with 24 randomly generated values between 100000 and 100010.

I then sorted them in ascending order in a single column:

```
100002
100002
100002
100002
100002
100003
100003
100003
100003
100003
100003
100004
100004
100005
100006
100007
100008
100008
100008
100008
100010
100010
100010
100010
```

I'd like to rename the above IDs :

```
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
4
5
6
7
7
7
7
8
8
8
8
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you have them ordered like that, you can just mark the first record as 1, then compare each record to its predecessor. If the record is different to its predecessor, increment it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula like this (enter in B2 and fill down)

[image]

EDIT:

For unsorted data:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,A$1:B1,2,0),MAX(B$1:B1)+1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!